# Getting Model from within Collection

Tags: php, oop, laravel

Something very basic but I'm having a hard time solving this.

I have a list of users in the database that show as online users. I am fetching these users by their user_id

**Model**

```
public function scopeloggedInUser($query){
        return $query->select('user_id')->get();
}
```

when I `var_dump` or `dd` it shows that its a collection of a list of currently logged in users. (Said it was super simple).

[image]

I need to fetch those individual users. How do I dilute this to the individual user within the Online Model.

Within the Controller

```
public function index(Online $online)
        {
            $activeuser = $online->loggedInUser();
            return view('user.user', compact('activeuser'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your online-model specify a relationship to the real user like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

In your view you can now access each user in your foreach-loop like this:

```
foreach ($activeusers as $user)
{
    echo $user->user->username; // or whatever fields you need
}
```

But to be honest: in your case I wouldn't set up a new database table and new model if you need this functionality.

Move your logic to your User model and add a boolean field to your user table and change your query-scope to this (again: in your user model)

```
public function scopeOnline($query){
    return $query->where('online', 1);
}
```

You also shouldn't do a get() within a scope because then you have no more access to the query builder. For example: you want all logged in users that are female.
With get: not pretty.

Without get:

```
User::online()->where('gender', '=', 'female')->get();
```

Comment: I would advise you read http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session. Your suggestion to add this to the User model would make my model very muddy, and my database very muddy.

Comment: Well maybe you show us all your code and not just part of it if you expect everyone to understand how your model works. It looks to me like you are storing online users in a separate table in the database.
And my suggestion really doesn't "mud up" your code. Its 3 lines and 1 column in the database.